# CakePHP unable to delete associations by cascade or beforeDelete()

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm on CakePHP 2.6

I want to delete several dependent models...

```
Users             hasMany ConversationsUser (join model)
ConversationsUser belongsTo User
                  belongsTo Conversation
Conversation      hasMany ConversationsUser
```

All relationships are `dependent => TRUE`

When I delete a User, I want all ConversationsUser to be deleted, as well as all Conversations.

Currently, only the ConversationsUser get deleted. The Conversations remain.

Theory: Maybe cascade doesn't work recursively, across multiple relationships...

So I add this to ConversationsUser model

```
public function beforeDelete ( $cascade = true ) {
    $this->log( $this->conversation_id );
    $this->log( $this->ID );

    #delete all conversations
    $this->Conversation->delete( $this->conversation_id );

    return TRUE;
}
```

This STILL doesn't work... and neither property appears in the logs, although the timestamp DOES (so I know the callback is running).

1. Why are those properties not defined in the `beforeDelete()`
2. Why isn't my cascading deleted working.

NOTE: In case it's relevant, all my models use the Containable behavior

**Update:**
As there seems to be some confusion about what I'm trying to do, I'll provide some context. The app allows two different users to conduct a "Conversation" which hasMany Messages. The user's membership in the conversation is defined by a hasMany relationship with a ConversationsUser (join table) model. If an administrator deletes one of the users in the conversation, all of that user's messages, conversations, and ConversationsUser(s) need to be deleted... *as well as* the ConversationsUser of the **other** participant(s) in the deleted Conversation(s). Otherwise those other users are left having a conversation with no one and things break.

Comment: You cannot "cascade" a delete from User to Conversation because, by your data model, there may be other Users associated with the Conversation you are trying to delete.

Comment: @AgRizzo Do you mean "cannot" because it's a bad idea? Or "cannot" because CakePHP won't allow it? I want the entire conversation (including other users' association with it) to be deleted.

Comment: You cannot from a database referential integrity point of view. Your ConversationsUser table allows for records (User_id, Conversation_id) to have these 3 rows (1,1), (1,2) (2,1). When you delete User_id=1, the first two rows would be deleted.  You cannot delete Conversation_id=1 because of the remaining rows (2,1).  You need to delete row (2,1) before deleting the Conversation row

Comment: I don't quite follow. I want to delete ALL ConversationsUser(s) associated with the Conversation.

Comment: And I'm still not clear on whether you are explaining why this is not a good idea, or whether you are explaining why this is literally not possible (ex: a CakePHP restriction)

Comment: It is impossible from a database point of view (which implies Cakephp) to cascade (i.e., automagically without additional code) a delete from a User deletion that will delete all related Conversations. You need to write code that deletes all Conversations for a user, then delete that user.

Comment: I've updated the question with some context for what I'm trying to do. But it sounds like you might already understand. Are you proposing that I write a `beforeDelete()` for Users that deletes all of the user's Conversations?

Comment: @AgRizzo Side question: is what you are saying also an explanation for why nothing seems to be getting passed to the `beforeDelete()` I wrote for the ConversationsUser model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an incomplete answer - I can't write and test actual code right now.

In your User model, add a beforeDelete callback.  This callback needs to

1. Get a list of all Conversations for that user (e.g., `$this->ConversationsUser->findAllByUserId($this->id, array('conversation_id'))`)
2. Iterate through the array of conversation_id's from the previous step and delete each one (making sure to have Cascade=True) (e.g., `$this->ConversationUser->Conversation->delete($conversation_id,true);`
3. Return True, so the User record is deleted

You don't need a beforeDelete in the ConversationUser model.

This works:

```
public function beforeDelete( $cascade = TRUE ) {

    #delete all conversations
    $conversationIns = $this->ConversationIn->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('ConversationIn.user_id'=>$this->id)));

    foreach ($conversationIns as $conversationIn ) {
        $delete = $this->ConversationIn->Conversation->delete( $conversationIn['ConversationIn']['conversation_id'] );
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: BTW... I figured out the mystery about `$this->ID` not being defined in the callbacks... In my schema I named the field "ID" (uppercase) so I assumed the property would be the same. But it's NOT. CakePHP somehow converts it so I need to use `$this->id`. Strange.